# PassportJS без редирект

Tags: javascript, node.js, redirect, passport

Использую `passportJS` для регистрации через facebook. Перехватываю `CallbackURL` вот так:

```
app.get('/sign-up/facebook/callback',
passport.authenticate('facebook', {failureRedirect: '/sign-up' }),
function(req, res) {
    res.redirect('/');
});
```

Вопрос. Как можно перехватить `CallbackURL` при этом обойтись без редиректа?

Comment: Ну, Капитан Очевидность намекает, что это может быть связано с заменой `res.redirect('/');` на что-то другое.

Comment: Не, мне нужно чтобы оно вообще никуда не дергалось, не обновляло текущую страницу и не рыпалось на другие. Вариант К.О я, само собой, испробовал.

Comment: Только если открыть отдельное окошко, которому "дёргаться" можно. Потому что редиректы это часть протокола OAuth2, от неё вы никуда не денетесь. Фреймы и AJAX вам тоже не помогут.

Comment: Почему не поможет AJAX? Костыль написать можно. Вопрос в другом: пасспорт при успешной авторизации высылает не только нужную страницу в ответ, он так же выставляет куку сессии в браузер, которая хранится и оставляет пользователя залогиненым, даже если он перезагрузит страницу или закроет браузер. Будет ли работать такой механизм, если ответ получать AJAX-ом, я не знаю.

Comment: В любом случае, такой механизм авторизации с перезагрузкой страницы совершенно нормален, я бы не изобретал велосипеды.

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете пробовать логинится по адресу /sign-up/facebook/callback c помощью AJAX, по адресу res.redirect('/success'); при успешной авторизации, допустим, выдавать "1", при неудачной тут выдавать failureRedirect: '/sign-up' "0"

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: '/sign-up/facebook/callback',
    success: function (data) {
        if (data == 1) {
            console.log("user authorized")
            //....
        } else console.log("user not authorized")
})
```

Честно говоря, не знаю, будет ли такой ответ сервака выставлять куку сессии и вообще вариант странный. Пасспорт изначально поддерживает много стратегий авторизации, в том числе и обычную (локальную). Лично я привык, что как только нажимаю кнопку "Выйти", сайт редиректит меня на страницу логина, например "вконтакте" и "фейсбук" и переделывать такой механизм будет странно.